# What is constructor? What kind of function object can be called constructor?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I'm confused with this definition.
I look up in ECMA and it defines constructor as

> function object that creates and initializes obejects.

So, can any function object be called constructor?

Comment: a constructor can be thought as kind of template that defines of how an object is created. A function object might create an object, but it can differ from a constructor nonetheless at this point.

Comment: If you go by the spec, there's a part where it says: *A function object is not necessarily a constructor and such non-constructor function objects do not have a [[Construct]] internal method.* Examples exist such arrow functions, methods, Function.prototype, generator functions and async functions which are not constructors.

Answer (score 1):

In js its common to call a function *constructor* if its aim is to be called with the *new* operator:

```
var me = new Human;//Human is a constructor
```

However, human languages are not that strictly defined, so you can probably use it always, you just need to have good arguments for your usage. A good *arguable* case:

```
function Animal(name){//actually rather a factory function
  return {name};
}

var cat = new Animal("bob");//and now ? :/
```

Comment: *"actually rather a factory function"* That's what I thought initially too, but Wikipedia has this little remark: *"formally a factory is a function or method that returns objects of a varying prototype or class"*. So it seems one typically would only consider a function a factory if it returns different "kinds" of objects? It's all semantics really...

Comment: @felix kling now it gets tricky ;)

Answer (score 0):

> So, can any function object be called constructor?

But not every function creates or initializes objects. Consider this example:

```
function add(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

This function only adds two values.

> What is constructor? What kind of function object can be called constructor?

I'd argue that only functions that are intended to be called with `new` are supposed to be considered "constructors" (that includes functions created via `class`).

However, you can also create objects without calling a function with `new`:

```
function getPerson(name) {
   return {name: name};
}
```

Whether or not you consider such functions constructors is probably subjective.